# Django form linking 2 models by many to many field

Tags: django, forms, many-to-many, inline

I have two models:

```
 class Actor(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique = True)
     event = models.ManyToManyField(Event, blank=True, null=True)

 class Event(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique = True)
     long_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to create a form that allows me to identify the link between the two models when I add a new entry.  This works:

```
 class ActorForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
           model = Actor
```

The form includes both name and event, allowing me to create a new Actor and simultaneous link it to an existing Event.

On the flipside,

```
 class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
           model = Event
```

This form does not include an actor association.  So I am only able to create a new Event.  I can't simultaneously link it to an existing Actor.

I tried to create an inline formset:

```
 EventFormSet = forms.models.inlineformset_factory(Event,
       Actor,
       can_delete = False,
       extra = 2,
       form = ActorForm)
```

but I get an error

```
<'class ctg.dtb.models.Actor'> has no ForeignKey to <'class ctg.dtb.models.Event'>
```

This isn't too surprising.  The inlineformset worked for another set of models I had, but this is a different example.  I think I'm going about it entirely wrong.

Overall question: How can I create a form that allows me to create a new Event and link it to an existing Actor?

Comment: How many `Actor` s are involved in an `Event`? From my feeling, I would create a foreign key from `Event` to `Actor` in the first place.

Comment: I understand your point, but I think Many to Many is correct.  More than one actor can attend an event, and an Actor can attend multiple events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would put the ManyToMany on Event to begin with, but to each their own...

As for how to do it, you'd want to write a custom ModelForm (not an inline formset), let's call it EventForm. It would handle all of your event's fields and would also have a [ModelChoiceField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) or [ModelMultipleChoiceField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield) to allow selection of the Actor(s) involved. Then in your view you would split out the processing of the Event fields and the ForeignKey/M2M field.

Make sense? [alt text http://sonicloft.net/im/52](http://sonicloft.net/im/52)